# Android library published on bintray but is not available at jcenter

Tags: android, maven, bintray, jcenter

I have small library https://bintray.com/dekalo-stanislav/maven/assertions-android
It is available at bintray but I can not get it from jcenter(), see details below:

20 Jan: Version 0.0.1 was published, and synced with jcenter.

21 Jan: I got approval

> Your request to include your package /dekalo-stanislav/maven/assertions-android in Bintray's JCenter has been approved.

Now it is 23 Jan and library is not available at jcenter()

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
//        maven {
//            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/dekalo-stanislav/maven'
//        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'ua.com.dekalo.android:assertions-android:0.0.1'
}
```

If I try build application:

```
./gradlew assemble --info
```

It tries to get library from jcenter.bintray.com:

```
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://jcenter.bintray.com/ua/com/dekalo/android/assertions-android/0.0.1/assertions-android-0.0.1.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: https://jcenter.bintray.com/ua/com/dekalo/android/assertions-android/0.0.1/assertions-android-0.0.1.jar]
```

And result is next:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find ua.com.dekalo.android:assertions-android:0.0.1.
     Required by:
         MyApplication2:app:unspecified
```

However if I will add my repo directly, all will work, see commented block in build.greadle, but it is not that I intended to achieve.

```
//        maven {
//            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/dekalo-stanislav/maven'
//        }
```

So, my questions is **why my library is not available at jcenter** and **what to do to get it visible at jcenter**.
Will be happy for any suggestions, thank you in advance.

Comment: Browsing through jCenter here doesn't show your packages [http://jcenter.bintray.com/ua/com/](http://jcenter.bintray.com/ua/com/) 

After pushing your library to bintray, did you go to the package page and publish it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am from the JFrog Support-Team, and following your question above, we have found that this was caused due to an temporary issue on our end (already fixed).
We have replied to you through your Bintray inbox (on the same inclusion request thread) with some additional instructions.

For any further questions, please feel free to reach out through support@jfrog.com

Eran

Comment: Thank you Eran.
Initially I thought it was something on my side.